# Redirect SharePoint 2007 Site Collection URL

Tags: sharepoint, redirect

Hope you could help!

I would like advice on the best option to redirect the top level site collection URL to an alternative address already setup in Alternate Access Mapping.

1. Using the CEWP to redirect via html/script
2. IIS 6.0

Onve the web application was setup/installed, a few months later we decided to change the URL (Business requirement), therefore a redirect is advised without deleting/over writing the exisiting content as this must stay intact.

Please help how I can acheive this, For Example, primary URL is http://server.company.org and would like to redirect to http://name.company.org

Our setup is MOSS 2007, Windows Server 2003 SP2 64Bit, IIS 6.0

Comment: Why don't you change the content in the CEWP?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some great information from a Microsoft MVP that describes in detail your options for [URL redirects in Office SharePoint 2007](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349%2D3bb6%2D4087%2D94f4%2D7f95ff4ca81f&ID=48&Web=48e6fdd1%2D17db%2D4543%2Db2f9%2D6fc7185484fc). This blog post has helped me several times in the past since I don't setup redirect very often. (I try to use redirects as little as possible)